# How to get layers from current viewport in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, web-mapping, mapfish

In my web map application, I have developed the printing module by using Mapfish with Geoserver. While printing, I need to send the layers to geoserver only which are falls inside the current view port.

Is it possible?

Comment: I am not sure why layers outside the viewport are printing. In the json you are sending to geoserver are the scale and center values set? Also in the json are you seeing layers other than ones visible in your viewport?

Comment: Yes am sending scale and center. I have 10 layers, in that 4 layers are within viewport (in current screen view), remaing are in someother location i.e. I want to print those 4 layers only

Comment: Are you saying that after you print your map the printed pdf contains more that the 4 layers visible in the viewport and the extent of the printed map is larger than the viewport?

Comment: Yes..So I want to filter out the layers which are not in current view before sending them to print.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the scales in your config.yaml file do no match your map scales. I cannot think of what else would cause the behavior you are describing. Updating the config.yaml will require a restart of geoserver.